# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp''

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am trying to build a stock prediction algorithm =, but I'm unable to comply with my date. I want to predict the stock for the next 10% days. I've been getting a number of errors, this is what I'm stuck with currently `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'`

```
df = pd.read_csv('TATASTEEL.NS (1).csv', parse_dates=['Date'])  # import  stock data
df = df[['Date', 'Open', 'Adj Close', 'Low', 'High', 'Volume']]
df = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
df['PCT_CHNG'] = (df['Adj Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100.0
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['High'] - df['Adj Close']) / df['Adj Close'] * 100.0
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  # helping pandas to make out that the date  column represents..date
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
```

This shows me some output but is restricting me from applying the rest of the model, i.e:

```
forecast_col = 'Adj Close'
df.fillna(-999999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.1 * len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)  # shifting down 10 spaces that's all
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['PCT_CHNG_label'] = (df['Adj Close'] - df['label']) / df['Adj Close'] * 100.0

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))  # I don't know why we dropped label and kept the rest
y = np.array(df['label'])  # I understand that we might need label as a parameter in this case
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
print(len(X), len(y))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

Full traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Yash Vyas/My Projects/Internship/TataSteel stock prediction.py", line 30, in <module>
    X = preprocessing.scale(X)
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 141, in scale
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, ensure_2d=False,
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 598, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback.

Comment: It sounds like the field names are getting into the data.

Comment: well apparently you are multiplying date with float and that obviously wont work so you have to somehow convert that date into a number!?

Comment: @Matiiss yes. That is what I want to do. How do I do that?

Comment: @Barmar Traceback added

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'Date' to be one of the features I believe. So either drop date from X, or make date as the index before you divide X and y.

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
X = ...
y= ..
```

Guess it should work now. Else, paste the error completely and I could help out.

Comment: Added the set_index line after the features line. Received error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Yash Vyas/My Projects/Internship/TataSteel stock prediction.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = df.set_index('Date')
  File "F:\Yash Vyas\My Projects\Internship\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4550, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"`

Comment: And If i keep the 'Date' column in the feature list, I get this: `KeyError: 'Date'`